# VB.NET; removing background from bitmap

Tags: vb.net, bitmap

I have bitmap with some drawing in the center, and white background. Is there any way to remove background with VB.NET, and leave only the drawing inside?

Comment: if it is all the same color, you could set WHITE as the transparent color, but the pixels are probably not exactly white, so you'd have to get one to find out the actual RGB

Comment: I 've tried that before (with green background), but the 'transparent' appeared as white.

Comment: are you trying to make it transparent for display or for saving to file?  Toobar type bitmap use it all the time to mask out a backcolor to let the host's color show thru

Answer (score 1):

Bitmap has a method called MakeTransparent, with an overload that takes a color.